# Automatically restart a process after it exits

Tags: linux, process-management, node.js

I have a javascript program, which runs on nodejs. If I run the following command:

```
node app.js
```

It keeps running but sometimes it exits. But I want to start it again automatically when it exits.

Is there any command to do so for Linux systems? Note that I don't want to use cron jobs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Quick and dirty way :** If using bash then what about a simple bash script like :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while true
do
  node app.js
done
```

BTW, this is wrongdoing since you don't take into account the reasons why your task exited and there might be very good reasons for **not** restarting it. Not to say that it could also crash at startup, be oomkilled…

---

**More canonical way under a systemd-ized linux :** (suggested as part of @Kusalananda note and inspired by [The ultimate guide to deploying your node app on Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20180212163211/https://certsimple.com/blog/deploy-node-on-linux)) :

Assuming that app.js starts with the `#!/usr/bin/env node` declaration and the file app.js is marked executable,

Design a new service : Create a .service file in the `/etc/systemd/system` directory if needed system-wide or `~/.config/systemd/user` directory if only needed by your user, as follows :

```
[Unit]
Description=        #(Whatever String You Want)
After=              #(Any service that should be started before, ex. network.target)
[Service]
ExecStart=          #(Key in the absolute path of app.js)
Restart=always      #(This will ensure the automatic restart)
User=               #(TBD depending on your system & wishes)
Group=              #(TBD depending on your system & wishes)
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=   # (Absolute path of app.js working dir.)
[Install]
WantedBy=           # multi-user.target or default.target according to your needs
```

You should now be able to start it : `systemctl --user start service_filename`